# LaTeX Import Command Error while Nesting

Tags: pdftex, input, include, import, git

I am facing this issue while I am trying to use \import command from latex. I have nested document which is compiling on GitLab pipeline. My configuration uses sub-modules also. Please see the error message image file.

[image]

My directory structure like this on GitLab:

my_branch (SP2)

- some files related with project
- doc-operation-handook.tex main tex file (contains `\input{sub_system_main.tex}`)
- gitlab config files
- *sub_system_main.tex (specific for this repository to pipeline config. this file is being used under the test phases.)*
- SP1_BL1 sub-module directory

  - *sub_system_main.tex file (specific for this repository to pipeline config. this file is not related with the question please ignore it.)*
  - SYSTEM directory

    - system_main.tex (contains `\import{SYSTEM/}{system_section_1.tex}`)
    - system_section_1.tex
  - AOCS directory

    - aocs_main.tex (contains `\import{AOCS/}{aocs_section_1.tex}`)
    - aocs_section_1.tex (contains section specific content)
  - TCR directory

    - tcr_main.tex (contains same as above)
    - tcr_section_1.tex
    - tcr_section_2.tex
  - TCS directory

    - ... tex files
  - ... directories

I have one main latex file (doc-operation-handbook) which is under the SP2 repository and it is calling sub_system_main.tex under the same directorylike this:

```
\input{sub_system_main.tex}
```

In the sub_system_main.tex file again I need to call some other .tex files from **sub-module SP1_BL1** but this time I used `\import` command from LaTeX like this:

```
\import{SP1_BL1/SYSTEM/}{system_main.tex}
\import{SP1_BL1/TCR/}{tcr_main.tex}
\import{SP1_BL1/OBCS/}{obcs_main.tex}
\import{SP1_BL1/AOCS/}{aocs_main.tex}
\import{SP1_BL1/PCS/}{pcs_main.tex}
\import{SP1_BL1/TCS/}{tcs_main.tex}
```

I do not know where I am doing something wrong but maybe I am using`\import` command totally wrong. After this configuration when I run the pipeline from GitLab it gives me an error which I shared above.

But I have an other repository working properly which uses again sub-module future from GitLab. Only difference is between this repository and above one is in sub_system_main.tex files. In other other repository I am using `\import` command like this:

```
\import{SP1_BL1/}{sub_system_main.tex}
```

As you can see I am calling this time from sub-module sub_system_main.tex file in another repository (with sub-module) which contains every latex file listed above in a packaged way. But when I try to use it like this again:

```
\import{SP1_BL1/SYSTEM/}{system_main.tex}
\import{SP1_BL1/TCR/}{tcr_main.tex}
\import{SP1_BL1/OBCS/}{obcs_main.tex}
\import{SP1_BL1/AOCS/}{aocs_main.tex}
\import{SP1_BL1/PCS/}{pcs_main.tex}
\import{SP1_BL1/TCS/}{tcs_main.tex}
```

It gives me an error..

I think I am using `\import` command wrong at all. If you guys can help me on this issue I will be very appreciate for that.

Comment: You claim `\import{SP1_BL1/SYSTEM/}{system_main.tex}` in the question, but the error message says otherwise. You have, on line 6, `\import{SP1_BL1/../}{system_main.tex}`.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau thank you for your kind response! I am sorry I uploaded wrong image file and it is edited now. Error comes from while we are into the sub-module.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Under that sub-module which is SP1_BL1 I have SYSTEM directory. SYSTEM directory has two different latex file one of them is system_main.tex and the other one is system_section_1.tex. Simply system_main.tex has this command in it: `\import{SYSTEM/}{system_section_1.tex}` and system_section_1.tex is contains the content of the document as it is mentioning section 1.

Comment: You probably can't edit your question to make it correct, can you? It sounds from the comment that ... Question has been edited ... I'll look.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Well I am trying to explain more explicitly my question because of that it is updated. First time it was not very clear I think. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question still doesn't sound right. The sub_system_main.tex file must be in the same directory as your main tex file, since \input worked. You managed to get into the file SP1_BL1/SYSTEM/system_main.tex (which is not listed in the layout) using \import, and that seems to contain the failing \import command  `\import{SYSTEM/}{system_section_1.tex}`. Is that right?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau again I am sorry for the insufficient explanation. I am new in this community.. Thank you being patient on me. You may find the edited folder structure of my gitlab repository..

Comment: Not insufficient, just had some troubles. See the answer. Change `\import{SYSTEM/}{system_section_1.tex}` to `\input{system_section_1.tex}`.

Answer (score 1):

Using clarifications in comments, it seems you are caught half-way between wanting `\import` or `\subimport`.

```
 \import {full-path}{file}
 \subimport {path-extension}{file}
```

If you have done

```
\import{SP1_BL1/SYSTEM/}{system_main.tex}
```

and if the next files you want to load are in the same directory,
the system_main.tex file could use the full path again

```
\import{SP1_BL1/SYSTEM/}{system_section_1.tex}
```

but it is more sensible to just use

```
\input{system_section_1.tex}
```

It is this redirection of `\input` that is the point of import.sty.

Now let's assume a slightly different layout of files in directories.

```
 (main dir)  document_main.tex
    (module dir "MOD") module_main.tex
       (sections dir SEC) m_sec_1.tex, m_sec_2.tex
```

Then the main document file would say

```
\import{MOD/}{module_main.tex}
```

That module_main.tex file would say

```
\subimport{SEC/}{m_sec_1.tex}
\subimport{SEC/}{m_sec_2.tex}
```

And the "sec" files could use `\input` or `\includegraphics` without specifying a path.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Donald!

I found a solution like that which is now working smoothly on GitLab. I played only some `\import` and `\subimport` commands and most importantly I added "../" at the beginning of the path definitions of the `\includegraphics` command. I hope those definitions can help other ones..

Detailed Information about Configuration (Main Repository):

doc-operation-handbook.tex contains (first latex file in the nested configuration):

```
\input{sub_system_main.tex}
```

sub_system_main.tex contains (second latex file in the nested configuration):

```
\subimport*{SYSTEM/}{system_main.tex}
\subimport*{OBCS/}{obcs_main.tex}
\subimport*{AOCS/}{aocs_main.tex}
\subimport*{TCR/}{tcr_main.tex}
\subimport*{PCS/}{pcs_main.tex}
\subimport*{TCS/}{tcs_main.tex}
```

xxxx_main.tex contains (xxxx can be any sub-system name, third latex file in the nested configuration):

```
\subimport*{./}{xxxx_section_1.tex}
```

Detailed Information about Configuration (Sub-Module Repository):

doc-operation-handbook.tex contains (first latex file in the nested configuration):

```
\input{sub_system_main.tex}
```

sub_system_main.tex contains (second latex file in the nested configuration which is going into sub-module defined in GitLab):

```
\import*{SP1_BL1/SYSTEM/}{system_main.tex}
\import*{SP1_BL1/TCR/}{tcr_main.tex}
\subimport*{OBCS/}{obcs_main.tex}
\import*{SP1_BL1/AOCS/}{aocs_main.tex}
\import*{SP1_BL1/PCS/}{pcs_main.tex}
\import*{SP1_BL1/TCS/}{tcs_main.tex}
```

obcs_main.tex contains (third latex file in the nested configuration):

```
\subimport*{./}{obcs_section_1.tex}
```

Image files should be added like that (tcolorbox can be ignored):

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics*[scale=0.5]{../TCR/tcr_images/FOP_Transmitter_switch_over.pdf}\caption{Transmitter Switch Over FOP}
\par\end{centering}
\end{figure}
\end{tcolorbox}
```